# Get properties of eager loaded objects without running queries again

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running this query :

```
Music::where('title', $title)->with(['artists.images'])->get();
```

And as result, I have a list of music

```
array:4 [▼
    0 => Music {#276 ▶}
    1 => Music {#275 ▶}
    2 => Music {#274 ▶}
    3 => Music {#273 ▶}
]
```

And each music is related to artists (music in sung by 3 artists for instance)

```
// Music #1
...
relations: array:1 [▼
    "artists" => Collection {#269 ▼
        items: array:3 [▶]
    }
]
...
```

And each artists has a relation with images (an artist has 7 images for instance)

```
// Artist #1 of Music #1
...
relations: array:2 [▼
    "pivot" => Pivot {#329 ▶}
    "images" => Collection {#505 ▼
        items: array:7 [▶]
    }
]
...
```

All are working good.

But in my view file, when I do (in a `foreach` loop)

```
@foreach($music->artists()->where('type', 'feature')->get() as $feature)
    {{ $feature->name }}
@endforeach
```

It runs again many queries for achieve this. `$music->artists` should already be eager loaded so it don't have to run query again. And when I run `dd()` on it, it actually contains relations as mentionned above.

How can I simply get properties without running again those queries again?

Comment: have you tried to add 'artists' in your `with` function like: `->with(['artists','artists.images'])`?

Comment: Still the same result.. The thing is when I run `dd()`, all wanted relations are displayed. That means it has succesfully eager loaded the object. Now I would like to get those properties without running SQL queries again. As I can see, calling `$music->artists()->where(xxx)` will run the query again.

Comment: When I run `$music->artists`, no additionnal queries are executed. But when I run `$music->artists()->where(xxx)`, additionnal queries are executed.

Comment: while using `artists()` you create a new query.
An other way to check is to use normal php/blade condions in loop `if($artist->type == 'feature')`. Or if it's possible you can apply your where clause before you execute the query (before using `get()`)

Comment: The `type` field is not in the Artist object, it is in a pivot object. So I can't use `$artist->type`

Comment: Ahh, the solution is `$artist->pivot->type`.

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading relationships can be done like this

```
@foreach($music->with(['artists.images'] )->artists()->where('type', 'feature')->get() as $feature)
{{ $feature->name }}
@endforeach
```

If this doesn't work then replace your where with a filter like..

```
@foreach($music->with(['artists.images'] )->artists->filter(function($it){return $it->type===' feature'} ) as $feature)
{{ $feature->name }}
@endforeach
```